# Group a list of strings into custom objects using Java 8 streams

Tags: arraylist, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a list which is created from the following paragraph.

```
keyword "My super heading 1"
        s1: "Statement -----1----"
        Some random text here
        Some random text here
        s2: "The message is sent"
        Some random text here
        here
        here
        here

keyword "My super heading 2"
        s1: "Statement -----2----"
        Some random text here
        Some random text here
        s2: "The message is sent"
        Some random text here
        here
        here
        here

keyword "My super heading 3"
        s1: "Statement -----3----"
        Some random text here
        Some random text here
        s2: "The message is sent"
        Some random text here
        here
        here
        here
```

I have a custom Object Modal as : `StatementModal:`
`String keyword`;
`String s1`; 
`String s2`;

I have read this text file as :

```
   //Read File
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {
        stream.forEach(line-> lines.add(line));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am trying to collect this as a List. Each containing `keyword`, `s1`, `s2`.
Is this possible using the stream API or I will have to write my custom business logic in here.
Any guidance or approach on how can I track a new `StatementModal` object everytime the loop iterates will be very helpful.

Comment: The object structures and the goal is unclear.

Comment: Let me add expected ouput in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, please do.